# Is there an easy way to identify parent Flows from subflows?

Tags: visual-workflow

I thought it might be possible by querying using the [Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm#FlowSubflow) metadata object, but doesn't appear to be possible as it returns an error. Is there a better way?

Comment: There's no parent link in a subflow; you'd need to look at all Flows that had a reference to the subflow. One easy way to do this would be in the IDE using text-based search

Comment: Thanks @cropredy for confirming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no parent link in a subflow

**Workaround:**

You'd need to look at all Flows that had a reference to the subflow. One easy way to do this would be in the IDE using text-based search.

The parent flow will contain the API name of the subflow as shown here:

```
<subflows>
    <name>SomeElementApiName</name>
    <label>Some Element Label</label>
    ...
    <flowName>SubFlowApiName</flowName>   <=== here
    <inputAssignments>
        ...
    </inputAssignments>
    <storeOutputAutomatically>true</storeOutputAutomatically>
</subflows>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to (IN A SANDBOX) delete the subflow. You'll then get an error saying:
"Can't delete because it's referenced by Flow X"
"Can't delete because it's referenced by Flow Y"
"Can't delete because it's referenced by Flow Z"